# Filtering depending upon the text string given in the text input field - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an javascript array object, each object consists of rating, comment and author field. I want to filter the comments as follows...!

The user types a keyword, lets say "Rating" in the input field, and the list is sorted out in ascending order of rating using a filter. The user types another keyword lets say "author" and the list is ordered in ascending order of the authors.

I do not want to use two inputs, I want the same input to be used for multiple filtering by using angular filter "orderby"

Comment: Do you want to filter or sort?

Comment: I want to sort out the results using angular filter - orderby

Comment: Create an input `<input type="text" ng-model="fieldToSortBy" ng-model-options="{updateOn:'blur'}"/>`
and then do `ng-repeat="list | orderBy:fieldToSortBy"`

Comment: Thanks @joel kornbluh